# fetching a row from table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Having this data:

[image]

I am running this code:

```
SELECT student_info.student_name,student_info.department,student_info.marks,
rank() over (order by student_info.marks desc) score  from student_info ;
```

and getting:

[image]

I want first two records alone with rank with out using rownum

Comment: "i want first two records alone with rank" - what does that mean?

Comment: i'm sure you have checked the two photos i attached , the second one is the result of above query it gives rank to all the records , with respect to that , i want the records of first rank holders alone

Comment: Yes, I saw screenshots you posted, but didn't understand what you meant to say by that. OK, @Zaid posted how to do it (has errors, but - that's the general idea).

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this please, I think this is what you need

```
SELECT student_name, department, marks, score
  FROM (SELECT s.*, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY marks DESC) AS score
          FROM student_info s)
 WHERE score = 1
```